# Bitnami Tomcat Version 8.5.16-0 (very old version), how to proxy by servername

Tags: tomcat, bitnami

I'm running a very old bitnami stack (Version 8.5.16-0), but I'm not able to update it now.

I need to configure it to proxy to another service running in another port by using the `ServerName`.

I tried this, but it not works:

I added to `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.mycompany.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
</VirtualHost>
```

So, when I access my `http://mycompany.com` I need it to continue to access the default AJP proxy configuration to the tomcat. But, when I access `http://sub.mycompany.com` I need to proxy to that custom service running on port 3001.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Bitnami Engineer here,

Adding that custom VirtualHost in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf` is the correct way to do this. I just launched the same solution you are using and added this to that file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://www.google.com/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I do not have a service running in the port 3001 but I configured Apache to redirect the connections to google.com. After restarting Apache

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

I verified that the configuration is correct

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-57-221:/opt/bitnami$ curl -LI 35.168.7.34
HTTP/1.1 200 200
Date: Thu, 20 Aug 2020 08:02:44 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"3660-1499251067000"
Last-Modified: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 10:37:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3660

bitnami@ip-172-31-57-221:/opt/bitnami$ curl -LI 35.168.7.34.nip.io
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 20 Aug 2020 08:02:47 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Date: Thu, 20 Aug 2020 08:02:47 GMT
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: Thu, 20 Aug 2020 08:02:47 GMT
Cache-Control: private
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2020-08-20-08; expires=Sat, 19-Sep-2020 08:02:47 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure
Set-Cookie: NID=204=qoK5Dqh-YCXNgqKmQQVLwHmxmLc7Pa7xoWcPc5iNnb_AqNTdDffYK7dpjoLFalVKEaS-vsKRcNUeJlLkO3GN-jNI4BUGzT0V2--66luMecjNoUWXcriPM8UhX2KtEqFd3Qw2Iu9NE10qeAnvhbDHw34sLDnheaYokmEeUALrSpg; expires=Fri, 19-Feb-2021 08:02:47 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
```

As you can see, the request that used the custom VirtualHost got redirected to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

In order to debug your problem, I'd follow these steps:

- Check that the server that is using the port 3001 is working properly

```
curl -LI localhost:3001
```

- Ensure the requests to `sub.mycompany.com` is using your custom virtual host. You will need to ensure that sub.mycompany.com is not set as the default domain in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` file and that you didn't include that domain in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` file either. You can try using the code I posted above to test the virtual host.
- Remember to restart Apache after applying any change to the configuration

I hope this information helps